# Firestore ACL: Limiting write permissions for an object to the user who created it?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, acl

I have two nodes: `users` and `lists`. I've structured it so that a `User` object has an array of `listIds` pointing to `List` objects it has created/has access to. However, how do I limit writing to that list to only that specific user? I'm not sure how to access the user's properties or if there's a better way to structure this.

```
user: {
  name: String,
  id: String,
  listIds: [String]
}

list: {
  name: String
  id: String
  itemCount: Int
  ...
}
```

```
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /lists/{listId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I did as Frank recommended, and modified my data, so that a user has an array of list ids, and a list has an array of user ids (contributors).

```
user: {
  name: String,
  id: String,
  listIds: [String]
}

list: {
  name: String
  id: String
  itemCount: Int
  userIds: [String]
  ...
}
```

I've updated my rules for /lists, however, I'm now seeing permission issues.

```
    match /lists/{listId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.userIds;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `get` that user document and check if the UID is `in` its `listIds` field with something like:

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && 
   listId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.listIds;
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [accessing other documents in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) and [attribute and role bases access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access).

---

In general I'd recommend duplicating the data about what user(s) have access to each list in the list document itself because it both saves you a document read charge for each read operation, and it makes the rules more readable/scalable.

So this would lead to have a `userIds` array field in your `list` documents and then you'd do this in the rule:

```
allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && 
   listId in resource.data.listIds;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Frank. So I did, as you recommended, and duped the data (a user has an array of list ids, and a list has an array of users (contributors)).  I've updated my answer to showcase my rule, however, I'm getting permission issues :/.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code that you use that isn't work, and a screenshot of a document you'd expect to be returned/modified by that code?

Comment: Hey @VAlexander. Any update here? Without seeing the *code* that isn't working against the rules, it'll be hard to say why the approach I outlined isn't working for you.